# Unable to import JPEG's for material texture

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders

I'm trying to import a JPEG for texturing. If the image I download is a PNG, then it is available in the shading tab and I can drag and drop it into the materials window and apply it as a texture (refer to pic 1 below). However, if the Image I download is a JPEG it appears greyed out and then when applied I get a violet color applied where my texture would be applied. (I'm assuming that violet is like an error code?)

Is blender 2.8 not able to make a textures from JPEG's?

---

To be clear the first picture is of a random PNG that works but is not what I want to apply. The second picture has the JPEG that I want to use but isn't working. I know I could probably find a work around by converting the JPEG to a PNG, but the question is is about Blender 2.8 limitations.

[image: 2]
[image: 1]

Comment: There aren't any limitations in Blender regarding opening and usage of files in JPG format. Maybe that is a bug; from the looks of UI Blender can't even load a color space selector which means at least not-a-normal behaviour. As usual, try to make sure that JPG is located in the place avaiable for Blender given the system permissions, if all is ok and you tried newest version report a bug over at developer.blender.org

Comment: When you get pink it means that blender cannot find the image in the specified path, or cannot load the file correctly. Open the Image editor window and see if your image loads there.

Comment: @susu facepalm. Looks like there is something funny on my end with how I downloaded and saved that jpg as other jpg's are working.. and the one in question is corrupted. Sorry about that, thanks for the help.

Comment: @AndrewMyers please write an answer in the answers section. Other users that run into a similar situation might find it helpful.